# Change class or style of specific element using events React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-bootstrap

I am having difficulties with React, I created a few hidden overlay divs within their own respective Card parent using map. I want the overlay div to be visible, but only for the Card that my mouse is hovering over. I'm using bootstrap-react.

```
  const [showResults, setShowResults] = React.useState(false);
  const onEnter = () => setShowResults(true);
  const onExit = () => setShowResults(false);

{filterDataState &&
            filterDataState.map((type: any) => (
              <Col className='p-0 mClass' onMouseEnter={onEnter} onMouseLeave={onExit}>
                      <div className={ showResults ?  undefined :'d-none' } > overlay placeholder</div>
                <Card className='m-auto' bg='dark' text='white' key={type.id} style={{}}>
                  <Card.Img src={type.img} />
                  <Card.Header className='text-center'><h6>{type.nome}</h6></Card.Header>
                  <Card.Body className='text-center'>{type.content}</Card.Body>
                </Card>
              </Col>
            ))}
```

The main problem is that every time I hover over the Card, the overlay div is displayed on all Cards, as opposed to just the one I hovered on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the key or an ID to be sure witch is the card that is mouse enter:

```
const [showResults, setShowResults] = React.useState(false);
  const onEnter = (id) => setShowResults(id);
  const onExit = () => setShowResults(false);

{filterDataState &&
            filterDataState.map((type: any) => (
              <Col className='p-0 mClass' onMouseEnter={onEnter(type.id)} onMouseLeave={onExit}>
                      <div className={ showResults === type.id ?  undefined :'d-none' } > overlay placeholder</div>
                <Card className='m-auto' bg='dark' text='white' key={type.id} style={{}}>
                  <Card.Img src={type.img} />
                  <Card.Header className='text-center'><h6>{type.nome}</h6></Card.Header>
                  <Card.Body className='text-center'>{type.content}</Card.Body>
                </Card>
              </Col>
            ))}
```

add to the onEnter function  the id param and check it with `showResults === type.id`

Comment: onMouseEnter={() => onEnter(type.id)} instead of onMouseEnter={onEnter(type.id)}, otherwise excellent idea, thanks so much man